# Changing the current object that the label system refers to

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to somehow refer to the proof of a theorem as the theorem itself.

How does `\label` actually be able to tell that it is currently inside this theorem? Is there some way to fool the label system (e.g. by changing the value of some macros) so that even if it is currently outside that theorem, it still thinks that it is inside the theorem?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,create-theorem}
\CreateTheorem{theorem}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm}
    Some text.
\end{theorem}

Some text.

\begin{proof}[Proof of the {\cref{thm}}]
    % perhaps do something here
    \label{proof-thm1}
    Some text
\end{proof}

\cref{proof-thm1} % I would like this to be "theorem 1"

\end{document}
```

> The motivation for this question is that in the package `cleveref-usedon`, if one turns on the `usedby` mode, then for this functionality to work properly, the `proof` environments has to be contained inside the corresponding theorem-type environment, which is not quite an ideal way to write. Thus I wonder if there is some way to fool the label system so that it would think that it is labeling another type of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to store the value of `\cref@currentlabel` for the environment that you'd like to refer to, and restore that value before you set the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,create-theorem}
\CreateTheorem{theorem}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm}
    \makeatletter
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \tl_gset:No \g_tmpa_tl { \cref@currentlabel }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \makeatother
    Some text.
\end{theorem}

Some text.

\begin{proof}[Proof of the {\cref{thm}}]
    \makeatletter
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \RenewCommandCopy \cref@currentlabel \g_tmpa_tl
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \makeatother
    \label{proof-thm1}
    Some text
\end{proof}

\cref{proof-thm1} % I would like this to be "theorem 1"

\end{document}
```

[image]